# Ansible run a role for all and for group

Tags: ansible

I have a role "totaldebug.users" which creates user accounts. for my playbook I have the following:

```
---

- name: Configure all servers.
  hosts: all
  become: true
  roles:
    - base
    - security
    - totaldebug.users

- import_playbook: tor.yml
```

Then within the imported playbook I have:

```
---
- hosts: tor
  roles:
    - totaldebug.motd
    - totaldebug.users
```

I then have the following group_vars:

all

```
users:
  - username: mainaccount
    uid: 2000
    groups: ['sudo']
    ssh-key: mypublic ssh key"
```

tor/vars

```
# Users
users:
  - username: serviceaccount
    uid: 666
    system: true
```

My expectation was that first it would run the "All" group and apply the user `mainaccount` then run the tor group and create the `serviceaccount` however it skips the main account and creates the service account.

My reason for doing this is that the main account I want on all servers, however the service accounts will be different or not required on other servers, Is there a way to achieve this or do I simply need to add the users under each group var and remove it from All?

Seems a bad design as then it takes me ages having to update multiple files with any account changes rather than just being able to change it at the top level all.

Comment: Would a construct like `when: ('tor' in group_names)` or `when: ("all" not in group_names)` help in your case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Variables returned from inventory group_vars do not depend on the group you are targeting, only on the [precedence rules](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#understanding-variable-precedence) (which can be somewhat [tuned](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/reference_appendices/general_precedence.html))

From the first link above, I suggest you make yours the advice:

> Teams and projects that agree on guidelines for defining variables (where to define certain types of variables) usually avoid variable precedence concerns. We suggest that you define each variable in one place: figure out where to define a variable, and keep it simple. For examples, see [Tips on where to set variables](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_variables.html#variable-examples).

Here is an example of how I would solve your current problem. I would first state (only an example, you can adapt):

1. Default list of users is defined in group `all`
2. Full list of users is calculated in group `all`
3. Other groups can define an additional list of users.
4. A machine can only be part of one group defining additional users.

From there:

- in **group_vars/all.ylm**

```yaml
_default_users:
  - username: mainaccount
    uid: 2000
    groups: ['sudo']
    ssh-key: mypublic ssh key"

users: "{{ _default_users + (_specific_users | default([])) }}"
```

- in **group_vars/tor.yml**

```yaml
_specific_users:
  - username: serviceaccount
    uid: 666
    system: true
```

You then only need to run your role once. It will create the default users and specific users if they exist for the particular host you are running the task on.

Comment: thanks for this it was spot on and works great :)